# Remove form input based on value in simple form collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

In my rails app I have a lesson model that belongs to a course. In the lesson new page, there is a collection of courses that can be selected for the lesson. Courses have several 'course_types' but the most important one for this question is the 'physical' course_type. This is the sample code

```
<%= f.association :course, collection: current_academy.courses.collect 
 { |u| [u.title, u.id] }, prompt: t("select") %>
```

On the same page, you can add a video link to the lesson

```
<%= f.input :video, label: t(".vimeo_link_to_video") %>
```

I want to be able to remove the video link if the course_type is 'physical'.

In my js, I have

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function() {
    document.querySelector('select[name="lesson[course_id]"]').onchange=changeEventHandler;
},false);
function changeEventHandler(event) {
    if(event.target.value == "97" ) {
      $(".vimeo").hide();
    }
    else {
        $(".vimeo").show();
    }
}
```

At the moment, I have to enter the course id, to make it work. What i want is to be able to derive the course type dynamically. So essentially i would like to do something like this in javascript

```
if(event.target.value == course.physical? )
```

How I can remove the video form input dynamically with Javascript when the value of the course is a 'physical' course_type.

Comment: Did you try anything yet? Please share the problem you are facing.

Comment: If you post in the raw html that gets generated you'll probably get a lot more help from JS people, the ruby is probably putting them off

Comment: 1. Add an event handler on change of course field 2. Check current value of course inside the callback 3. Toggle video field based on the value in (2). Details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change